# Backend setCookie does not set cookies in my browser for nextjs application

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

please have a look at this function

`const handleGoogleResponse = async(response) => {`

// Handle the response from Google Sign-In
  `const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/auth/google`, {`       `method: 'GET',`
 `headers: {`
  `'Content-Type': 'application/json',`
 `'auth': response.credential`
   `},`
  `});`
 `const userObject = await res.json();`

`localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userObject.user));`
};

What it basically does is to make a request to my backend after google authentication to sync firebase db and my own db. The expected behaviour for the backend is that it returns a user object and sets cookies in browser. Now this worked fine when i was working with a react application, but on migrating to nextjs i still get the user object, res 200 showing that request was succesfully carried out but no cookie is set in browser. I am guessing it has something to do with Nextjs SSR. Can anyone please help me out?

This is the component that makes the request:

```
`"use client";
import { baseUrl } from "@/lib/apiConfig";
const montserrat = Montserrat({
  weight: ["700", "600", "500"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
});


function Navbar() {
  const { user, isLoading } = useUser();
  const [displayCard, setDisplayCard] = useState<boolean>(false);



 const handleGoogleResponse = async(response) => {
  console.log(response)

  const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/auth/google`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'auth': response.credential
      },
  });
  const userObject = await res.json();

  localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userObject.user));
```

};
`I already made it a client component thinking it would help resolve the issue but still does not work.